# How can I remove the decimal parts from numbers in Kotlin?

Tags: android, kotlin

I'm using `OpenWeatherMaps` API for a weather app, but it shows decimal in some cities, how can I remove decimal parts from them?

```
override fun onPostExecute(result: String?) {
            super.onPostExecute(result)
            try {
                val jsonObj = JSONObject(result)
                val main = jsonObj.getJSONObject("main")
                val temp = main.getString("temp")+"°C"
                findViewById<TextView>(R.id.temp).text = temp
```

Comment: you can just convert to Int

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If you want everything before the dot there is [`substringBefore()`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.text/substring-before.html):

```
val temp = main.getString("temp").substringBefore(".") + "°C"
```

Comment: This is the best solution IMO, it uses the method designed specifically for the task and doesn't convert to a number just to immediately convert it back to a string.

Answer (score 4):

> toInt() is solution of your question

```
val jsonObj = JSONObject(result)
                val main = jsonObj.getJSONObject("main")
                val temp =  +"${main.getString("temp").toDouble().toInt()}°C"
                findViewById<TextView>(R.id.temp).text = temp
```

Comment: You get `NumberFormatException` when the string is e.g. "23.45".

Answer (score 0):

Seeing that you are using `getString()` and assuming the data sent from the server is like "31.23", the first thing that comes to my mind is just to split the string using the dot as delimiter and use the first value:

```
val temp = main.getString("temp")split(".")[0] +"°C"
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `getInt` not `getString`.

```
val temp = main.getInt("temp") + "°C"
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to remove the fractional portion of the number in a string, try something like

```
    val df = DecimalFormat("#")
    println("Foobar: ${df.format(100.10)}")
```

### Result:

Foobar: 100

Answer (score -1):

try this

```
  val temp = String.format("%.0f",main.getString("temp")) +"°C"
```

Comment: This would remove the digits after the decimal but leave the decimal point itself. Please don't post suggestions you haven't actually tested.